# The query is taking longer time to execute

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

This is the query where I am using three tables to join , using the output of two tables and joining with the third table. But while executing it is taking a longer time. Is there a way to reduce the execution time by making the changes in the query? For example, it is good to use "OR condition." Like this

AND (QH.HST_NET = hm.name or QH.HST_NS=hm.ns_main or QH.HST_P=hm.ip)

```
select * from lys_raw.lys_pras qh
    left join 
    (select em.name
    ,em.s_dom
    ,em.p_add
    ,em.pulldata,cm.eff_start_date,cm.eff_end_date
    ,em.hst_id
    ,case when cm.report is null THEN 'Ly Ele' else cm.report END report
    ,case when cm.seg is null THEN 'Ly Ele' else cm.seg END seg
    ,case when cm.reg is null then'Oope - Owner' else cm.reg END reg
    from mi.ami em
    left join 
    mi.ami_COMP_MAP cm on lower(em.COMP)=lower(cm.MI_COMP)
    where em.pulldata=last_day(em.pulldate)) hm on qh.lys_ins in('PI','GI','CW') 
    AND (QH.HST_NET = hm.name or QH.HST_NS=hm.ns_main or QH.HST_P=hm.ip);
```

Comment: Any approach will help

Answer (score 0):

You should consider your join clauses.

1. `lower(em.COMP)=lower(cm.MI_COMP)` is not ideal. Better to clean your data first - use a temp table if you need.
2. joining with ORs like this `(QH.HST_NET = hm.name OR QH.HST_NS  = hm.ns_main OR QH.HST_P = hm.ip)` is not ideal. You might be better using a UNION
3. `SELECT *` is an overhead when developing code. Try using `SELECT COUNT(*)` first, once that is fast, change it to `COUNT(*)`

Also, the code you posted has errors. Your `hm` select does not include all the column you joined on. If you are going to post to SO, you should take the time to at least post correct (and well formatted SQL). Anyway, this below might help you with some ideas...

```
WITH HM AS(
( select 
    em.name AS HST_NET
  , em.s_dom
  , em.p_add
  , em.pulldata
  , cm.eff_start_date
  , cm.eff_end_date
  , em.hst_id
  , case when cm.report is null THEN 'Ly Ele' else cm.report END report
  , case when cm.seg    is null THEN 'Ly Ele' else cm.seg END seg
  , case when cm.reg    is null then 'Oope - Owner' else cm.reg END reg
  from 
    mi.ami em
  left join 
    mi.ami_COMP_MAP cm
  on
    em.COMP = cm.MI_COMP
  where
    em.pulldata=last_day(em.pulldate)
) hm
, qh AS (
  select * 
  from
    lys_raw.lys_pras qh
  where 
    qh.lys_ins in('PI','GI','CW') 
)
          SELECT * FROM hm LEFT JOIN qh USING HST_NS 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM hm LEFT JOIN qh ON QH.HST_NS  = hm.ns_main
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM hm LEFT JOIN qh ON QH.HST_P   = hm.ip
```